# Odd vertical gap with multicol, scrreprt and parskip=half

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, koma-script, multicol, parskip

I'm having a weird vertical gap in one of my documents, which only is there when I use `multicol` together with `\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}`.

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
        \subsubsection{title}
        this \\
        is \\
        a long \\
        text
\vfill
\columnbreak
        \subsubsection{title}
        foo
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

I'd expect the "foo" to be at the top line of the left column, not on the bottom. What's going wrong there?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly standard `multicols` behaviour when the text in the first column is short:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \subsubsection{title}
  Broken text that spreads over two lines to demonstrate behaviour.
  \columnbreak
  \subsubsection{title}
  foo
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \subsubsection{title}
  Broken text that spreads over two lines to demonstrate behaviour.
Now extended to another line.
  \columnbreak
  \subsubsection{title}
  foo
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The `\subsection` has stretchable glue after it, and `multicols` uses it in the first example to try to balance the bottom of the columns.  When the difference is greater, there is not enough glue to achieve this.  (In your example you are seeing a larger vertical space as there is more glue available when the `parskip=half` option is set; suprisingly much as @lockstep points out.)

To over come this there is actually a simple solution using the `\raggedcolumns` command of `multicol`:

[image: Sample ragged output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \raggedcolumns
  \subsubsection{title}
  Broken text that spreads over two lines to demonstrate behaviour.
  \columnbreak
  \subsubsection{title}
  foo
\end{multicols}

Text below
\end{document}
```

I have added text below the `multicols` to demonstrate that there is no flushing of the page in this case, in contrast to the `multicols*` environment.

Comment: I've tried using `multicols*`, but then the `\vfill` did fill out the rest of the page instead of the minimum amount needed. This is visible by adding a `\section{another title}` after the `\end{multicols*}` which then lands on the next page.

Comment: I have now added a simpler suggestion to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't tell what's going on, I can offer a workaround based on the fact that things work as expected with `parskip=full`: Reduce the stretchability included in the definition of `parskip=half` (`plus 0.5\baselineskip`) to that of `parskip=full` (`plus 0.1\baselineskip`).

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
      \setparsizes{\z@}{.5\baselineskip \@plus .1\baselineskip}{%
        1em \@plus 1fil}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
        \subsubsection{title}
        this \\
        is \\
        a long \\
        text
\vfill
\columnbreak
        \subsubsection{title}
        foo
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `parskip=full` just makes the left column longer so the effect disappears.

Comment: The effect is still there with a `parskip=full` plus enlarged stretchability, so something else seems to be going on. Add the following to the OP's example: `\makeatletter\setparsizes{\z@}{\baselineskip \@plus .5\baselineskip}{1em \@plus 1fil}
\makeatother`

Comment: Agreed.  As I said in my answer this is associated to the last column balancing of `multicols`.

Comment: +1 for your answer because it offers an explanation, not only a workaround. Still, it's strange that KOMA-Script's stretchability for `parskip=half` is bigger than for either `full` or `off`. If the OP doesn't use my workaround, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I don't think you should delete your answer.  This observation about these `parskip` settings is interesting.

Comment: The larger glue of `parskip=half` makes sense, because it avoids `underfull \vbox` with `\flushbottom` if there are 1, 2, 3 or 4 `\par` on a page. I think having less than 5 `\par` per page is the normal case. So the larger glue makes a lot of sense.